# NCover coverage.xsl file missing

Tags: msbuild, ncover

This is my Ncover task portion in my MSBuild script

```
<UsingTask TaskName="NCoverExplorer.MSBuildTasks.NCover" AssemblyFile="$(Libraries)\NCoverExplorer.MSBuildTasks.dll"/>
<Target Name="NcoverCoverage">
    <NCover ToolPath="C:\Program Files\TestDriven.NET 3\NCover\1.5.8"
        CommandLineExe="C:\Program Files\TestDriven.NET 3\NUnit\2.5\nunit-console.exe"
        CommandLineArgs="MyTestProject.dll"
        WorkingDirectory="MyWorkingDirectory"
        LogFile="coverage.log"
     />
</Target>
```

This NCover task executes fine and creates an output xml file (Coverage.xml). This output xml file contains a reference to a xsl file (Coverage.xsl) which is missing in my machine.

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="coverage.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

I cant find this file anywhere. Due to this, hen I try to open the Coverage.xml file, it throws an error

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click   the Refresh button, or try again later. 

Access is denied. Error processing resource 'file:coverage.xsl'.
```

Where can i find my coverage.xsl file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage.xsl file is available in the install directory (C:\Program Files\NCover) once you install the NCover Community Edition located here:

http://www.ncover.com/download/current

NCover Support